# Python Pandas: Get rows where previous values are greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe in pandas:

```
   col1    col2
0     1    -0.5
1     2    -4.0
2     8     3.0
3     9     6.0
4     4   345.0
5     6    -7.0
6     7  3456.0
7    47     3.0
8     2     5.0
9     4   -78.0
```

I want to return only these rows, where the "col2" values of the previous 3 rows are greater than 0.
In this case:

```
5     6    -7.0
```

and

```
 9     4   -78.0
```

I have tried it with rolling but cant find a way.
Can you help me, please? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.rolling(3)` on `col2` to look at the window of 3 entries and then use `gt(0).all()` to check all these 3 entries being > 0.  As you want to check for the previous 3 entries not including current entry, we further use `.shift()`.   Then use `.loc` to locate such entries:

```
df.loc[df['col2'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.gt(0).all()).shift() > 0]
```

---

**Another soluton** without using `.apply()`, as inspired by Tom, is as follows:

```
df.loc[df['col2'].shift().gt(0).rolling(3).min().eq(1)]
```

Here, we use `.rolling(3).min().eq(1)` on the boolean series with `gt(0)` to check that all 3 entries have minimum of 1 (meaning that *all entries* must be `True`, since `True` is translated to `1` in calculations and `False` translated to `0`). *Effectively, we get the same effects as `gt(0).all()` in previous solution.*

This notion has the advantage that no matter what's the rolling window size, we still check for `min().eq(1)` without requiring to adjust this part of code when the rolling window size is changed.

---

**Result:**

```
   col1  col2
5     6  -7.0
9     4 -78.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to the answer by SeaBean, but without using the `apply`:

```
>>> df[df['col2'].shift().gt(0).rolling(3).sum().eq(3)]
   col1  col2
5     6  -7.0
9     4 -78.0
```

You use `shift` so you don't have to consider the previous 3 rows, rather each row and the 2 behind it.  Then make a mask of positive values (`.gt(0)`), and with a rolling window of 3 over that mask, check which groups have a sum of 3.